# html - text overflow in "width:100%" page

Tags: html, css

I have a page where links overflow the page.
I wish they would stay on the line below.

I put the follow lines:
`display:inline-block; overflow: auto;`
But didn't work.

```css
.hashtag {
            font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
            padding: 28px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: auto;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 5px 2px;
            background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8);
            color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 1;
```

```html
<a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;line-height: 1;" class="hashtag" id="load2">TODAY</a>&nbsp;<a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;overflow: auto;" class="hashtag" id="load3">LIVE</a>&nbsp;<a href="player-hd/podcasts.html" style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;line-height: 1;overflow: auto;" class="hashtag">PODCASTS</a>
```

(Sorry my English)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your CSS is missing a closing `}` and your HTML opens with an obsolete `<center>` element and closes with a `<span>`. Please fix your code.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align:middle;` to `.hashtag` to stop the first element being dropped down. You can also add `white-space: nowrap;` to the parent `center` element to stop the elements wrapping.

```css
center {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hashtag {
            font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
            padding: 28px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: auto;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin: 5px 2px;
            background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8);
            color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 1;
            vertical-align:middle;
         }
```

```html
<center><a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;line-height: 1;" class="hashtag" id="load2">TODAY</a>&nbsp;<a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;overflow: auto;" class="hashtag" id="load3">LIVE</a>&nbsp;<a href="player-hd/podcasts.html" style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;line-height: 1;overflow: auto;" class="hashtag">PODCASTS</a></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)

Comment: Sorry doesn't seem to be working. Checking why it isn't now.

Comment: @SergioC This should be what you were after now.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks again.